# angular timer unable start multiple timers separatly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-timer

I use `ng-repeat` in `uib-tabset` and in each tab is timer. Each timer has a Start button so each timer can be started on some action.

```
<uib-tabset active="activeTab">
<uib-tab ng-repeat="question in vm.QuestionsList" index="question.Index" disable="question.disabled">
    <uib-tab-heading>
        Q{{question.Index}}
    </uib-tab-heading>

    <timer countdown="question.TimeForQuestionInSeconds" interval="1000" finish-callback="vm.questionTimeOut()" autostart="false" id="q{{question.Index}}-timer">
        Remaining time : {{countdown}} second{{secondsS}} <br />
        <div class="progress progress-striped active {{displayProgressActive}}" style="height: 15px;"><div class="bar" style="width: {{progressBar}}%;"></div> </div>
    </timer>

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" ng-click="vm.startTimer()" ng-disabled="vm.TimerRunning">Start</button>
</uib-tab>
</uib-tabset>
```

in my controller I have this function:

```
public startTimer() {
            this.$scope.$broadcast('timer-start');
            this.TimerRunning = true;
        }
```

but it start all my timers. I found this solution here https://github.com/siddii/angular-timer/issues/166

```
document.getElementById('q1-timer').start();
```

But I get this error `Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementById(...).start is not a function` and dont know why. Is there any other way?

Comment: What's `q1-timer'`?

Comment: generated id of each timer `id="q{{question.Index}}-timer"`

Comment: where's your timer listener?

Comment: https://github.com/siddii/angular-timer/blob/master/dist/angular-timer.js#L82